# Where is the PHP folder on XAMPP for MAC OS 10.12 system?

Tags: php, macos, xampp, command-line-interface

I've been tried to export a custom PATH on `~/bash_profile` file by adding:

```
export XAMPP_HOME=/Applications/XAMPP
export PATH=${XAMPP_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
export PATH
```

But this doesn't work because the PHP path is incorrect.

Furthermore, I also ran `phpinfo()` and get the `Configuration File` but the path is `/opt/lampp/etc` that doesn't exist.

Therefore, I just need to change the default PHP CLI from version 5.5.6 to 7.1.11.

Can someone here please give me a help!!!?

Comment: did you download a xampp for linux? I think they have one for mac too?

Comment: I've downloaded XAMPP for MAC OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours searching on Google, I've reached at this video that pointed me to the right point: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vT5luUaAcQ8

Yes! Now I can change my PHP CLI version to any other since 5.3.

## Here are the steps from the video:

1. To get started, go to https://php-osx.liip.ch/
2. Scroll down to the One Line Installation section and copy the command for the version of PHP that you want to install
3. Open up a Terminal window
4. Paste the command and press Enter
5. The PHP OSX installer will take care of loading the new version of PHP into the pre-installed copy of Apache
6. If you want to run the new version of PHP from the command line, you’ll need to update your PATH
7. To do that, you’ll need to add a line to your .bash_profile file.
8. Type vim ~/.bash_profile and press Enter
9. Press Shift-G to jump to the end of the file
10. Press i to enter Insert mode
11. Type export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH
12. Press Escape to exit Insert mode
13. Type :wq to save and quit
14. Now you can close your Terminal window and open a new window to use the new path

Answer (score 0):

export PATH=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin:$PATH

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.